# Using US iPhone 6 in Europe

Tags: europe, cellphones

In August, I'll be leaving for Europe and would like to use my iPhone 6. Last time I went, I used applenberry's unlock services online for my iPhone 5 so that I could use my phone on a foreign carrier (Drei mobile), however the site's unlocking part has been closed. Do you know where I could get an IMEI unlock for my iPhone before I go abroad?

Comment: From your carrier.

Comment: Do you want to use your phone with your existing network in europe? Or do you want to use a european SIM in your phone? Because the answer is different depending on what you want.

Comment: I'd be using a European sim

Comment: From what country _and_ carrier did you obtain the iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

This question has absolutely nothing with SE travel. There many online websites that can do that yet there are triple that amount of scammers.

Genuine websites rarely do individual devices and most of the time you have to load your account with £50 or so.

Like one of the comments suggested contacting **your carrier** is what you should first. Having said that [this website](http://www.aunlock.com/) is reliable, I personally have unlocked over 200 devices using their service.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to post this in the wrong section :P